# How to creat different user type in drupal?

Tags: 7, users

I want to create two different type of users for example internal and external users. For internal users need to be authenticate against different database. Any suggestions?

Comment: If I understand your question right, you want some users (Local) access different website than your live website?

Comment: I need to authenticate some internal users from different database  as well as I have some drupal users also.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unless you wish to write a custom module with direct access to the second database, with its own login system, the only way this is going to work is with direct manipulation of the drupal database, renaming tables, and using 'Create View ...' to give you access to the information. The amount of work, maintenance problems, and security implications would be horrendous.

If the number of 'internal' users is fairly static, my suggestion would be to use the [User Import](http://drupal.org/project/user_import) module, and give them all a role of 'Internal', using the user permissions to control their abilities on the site. Any new Internal users could be added manually.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you redirect each user based on his IP address, to a different domain, so take a look at these modules:

[Domain Access](http://drupal.org/project/domain)

[IP to Locale](http://drupal.org/project/ip2locale)

Update:
Prior to your comment, take a look at this [doc](http://drupal.org/node/18429)

Comment: Thanks for your effort but I need to connect that DB based on some condition then How can I maintain user activity record in drupal.

Comment: the question below answers to your comment I guess